# Outputting customers who haven't repeat ordered since a specific date range in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have searched around but have not found anything which seems to be totally relevant so I'm asking for some help.

I have a single table which contains orders, people can have multiple orders. I need to be able to select people who purchased in 2 years ago (April 2012) where they haven't purchased since, to identify unique people I am using email address as there is no unique customer ID. Here is the order table fields:

```
orderid,order date,name,email
```

I have limited SQL knowledge, but my approach previously has been to output a table of orders from April 2012 and another table from May 2012 to the present date. I then compare the 2 tables to find customers who haven't ordered since.

I can't help but feel like there is a more efficient way to do this in one query. Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Sam.

Answer (score 3):

I would use LEFT JOIN here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT order1.email
FROM `order` order1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email FROM `order` WHERE orderdate >= '2012-05-01') order2
  ON order1.email = order2.email
WHERE orderdate < '2012-05-01'
  AND order2.email IS NULL;
```

The main query is checking for people who ordered before May 2012, and the `LEFT JOIN` query is checking (with `order2.email IS NULL`) for people who have NOT ordered since then.

Comment: You are welcome, mate. Can you accept my proposition as the answer then? It would be great :)

Answer (score -1):

You can write this query without any join something like this:-

```
select email
from order
where email not in (select email from order where order_date >"April 2012")
  and order_date < "April 2012";
```

Here, first condition filter outs all customer who have bought in last two years, and from second condition you get the customers who have bought two years ago.

As suggested, query with `NOT EXISTS` will go like this:

```
select o1.email
from order o1
where not exists (select 1 from order o2 where o2.order_date > "April 2012" and o1.email = o2.email)
  and o1.order_date < "April 2012";
```

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL performs very poorly with `IN` if the sub query returns a large number of results.  Better to use joins, or NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Your latter query probably needs a condition on matching email too, otherwise you'll get no results at all if _any_ order exists from after April 2012.

Comment: The bigger flag would be the use of a reserved word as a table identifier!

Comment: Also, these queries are not equivalent.